# .Net core 3.1 how can catch all errors and find the exception place in the helper classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

1. I'm using `app.UseExceptionHandler()` middleware to catch the exceptions, but some errors like ex: `new Uri(" empty str ")` does not throw the error to the exception controller directly please find screen1 and 2?
   [image: Screen 1 when the error occurred]

   after press continue the exception will throw to the exception controller
   [image: Screen 2 after press continue]
   why the exception does not go to the exception controller directly?
2. and how to catch the exceptions that occurred in helper classes or any class not inherit of Controller class without use (try and catch) because I need a dynamic way to catch any exception in all project files?

Comment: You have the option to "break on exceptions" enabled. You can disable this for specific exception types... hit the little down arrow in your first image and then uncheck the box or use the exception settings *window*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add method with function call back as a parameter in your base controller.

For example:
Base controller:

```
 public class BaseUIController
 {
  protected async Task<IActionResult> HandleExceptionCall(Func<Task<IActionResult>> call)
    {
        IActionResult result;
        try
        {
            //Your actual function call back pass here
            result = await call();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //Here, you can handle all the exception.
           result = View("Error");
        }
        return result;
    }
 }
```

For example: Your child controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : BaseUIController
{        
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployees()
    {
        return await HandleExceptionCall(async () =>
        {
           //Your api call here
           //Now, If any exception raised, you can handle in your base controller function.
        });
    }
}
```